# SVN-How to commit a file to separate repositories

Tags: svn

I'm looking out for a solution where I can save a file to 2 different repositories using SVN.

I have to 2 repositories one is my local repository in my system and the other is the repository in production server when I make change to a file in local, How can I commit the file to 2 different repositories in different locations at a time.

The local repository is setup in such a way it is feasible for the developer. And the production repository has a different folder structure.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this is not possible. A working copy can be under the control of only one repository at a time.

This may be achievable using a post-commit hook, but it's going to be complicated.

The easiest way might be having two directories locally, the one mirroring the other. You would still have to do two commits, though.

This sounds a bit like bad practice. Are you sure this is sensible and necessary? Is there not a better solution for your scenario, an [external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html) for example?

Comment: What do you mean by an external?

Comment: @user see the link. It's a pointer to another repo inside a repo

Comment: Oops @svinto we are both guilty of linking to grossly outdated versions of the manual :) The current one is http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html

Comment: Can we make the another repo inside a repo point to the production repository path?

Comment: The idea of using externals looks interesting.

Comment: @user you mean like an infinite loop? Not sure whether that's possible

Comment: @svinto:  Be sure when linking references to the SVN Book that you use the latest version of the book (nightly) or next best release (1.5).  Yes, we all know you got the reference from some search engine (Google).  But with externals, some significant changes took place in 1.5 that were not available in the 1.0 version your site, which over six years old by the way.

Comment: @jgifford25 all true, but I feel this is something the SVN book team needs to fix: The 1.0 manual is the first Google result for `svn externals`, and no link to 1.5 is visible on page 1. I'll send an E-Mail to their mailing list.

Comment: @Pekka - I know that one of the guys who authors the SVN book actually works for Google.  I've shot them e-mail a time or two about it as well.

Comment: @jgifford25 thanks, that's great! I added an issue in their issue tracker. http://code.google.com/p/svnbook/issues/detail?id=109

Answer (score 1):

The only Subversion-only solution I can think of is to use hooks, more specifically a post-commit hook in your local server that submits stuff to the remote server. The obvious drawback is that you have to code the scripts yourself and it looks like a lot of work.

I assume such arrangement is a workaround to use local versions in your development. I believe that people normally use third-party software to accomplish it. You can:

- Install another version control system (such as [git](http://git-scm.com/), [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or [bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/)) for local versions. Just remember to omit your local versions database from Subversion.
- Use [SVK](http://svk.bestpractical.com/view/HomePage) on top of Subversion, so you can choose what to commmit to the remote repository.
- Use an IDE that features custom local versions.

Comment: +1 for mentioning distributed VCS, this may indeed be the better solution to the "local" problem. @user I always liked http://Hginit.com as a nice introduction to how DVCS works

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen http://wandisco.com/ ? This is what they do and more.